# Python variabale assignment

Tags: python, variables, python-3.6, variable-assignment

Greetings programmers,

I have an one particular question to ask - more precisely about python's behaviour when assigning variable. Let's assume this code (taken from Tensorflow's guide):

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I understand, that I cannot do the following:

```
train_images /= 250.0
```

-the object `train_images` is not writeable, thus I cannot change it.

But I can definitely do following, which I don't understand:

```
train_images = train_images / 250.0
```

Does it mean that when I "re-assign" the variable train_images, the python somehow automatically forgets about the old one and constructs the `train_images` as a new variable?

Please excuse my lack of python's behaviour knowledge - if there is an obvious answer just post some link to the explanation or some documentation where this case is described.

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

**EDIT:**

By "non-writeable" I meant that the object is read-only (when we print the array's description `print( train_images.flags )` we get the information from one of the lines that `WRITEABLE : False`

And more specifically when `train_images /= 250.0` is used, the program terminates and the following error is outputted:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code_01_fashion.py", line 31, in <module>
    train_images /= 250.0
ValueError: output array is read-only`

On the other hand `train_images = train_images / 250.0` runs just fine.

Comment: Are you sure `train_images /= 250.0` does not work? It should be treated the same as `train_images = train_images / 250.0` for immutable values, or `x = 1; x /= 250.0` would not work. What type is `train_images`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not writeable". What is the type of train_images? Exactly what error do you get when you try the `/=` operation? Python doesn't distinguish between these operations in the way you claim; you can have immutable types (eg tuples) but this would still work.

Comment: with `train_images /= 250.0` the interpreter terminates the program and prints the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code_01_fashion.py", line 31, in <module>
    train_images /= 250.0
ValueError: output array is read-only`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's important to know that this is not vanilla python. Keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data() returns a NumPy array. (NumPy is the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python. [About NumPy](http://www.numpy.org))

Is possible to disable a numpy array for **writing**. [Details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html)

When you're using the in-place operators (x /=250.0), you're explicitly asking to modify your object, but in this case you are not allowed.

If you want to check if your NumPy array is writeable you can run:

```
>> train_images.flags
```

and check the boolean in WRITEABLE

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : False
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

When you are doing something like:

```
train_images = train_images / 250.0
```

is similar to:

```
temp = train_images / 250.0
train_images = temp
```

So, in this case, you are creating a new object and reassigning the variable.